# Event's not firing & Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

after having 2-3 days being able to code without any problems, the youtube api seems to stopped interact with my webpage.
I'm using the iFrame-API as recommended by Youtube.

Regardless of the real project that stopped working, i tried to reproduce the differences between my final script and a working demonstration.
The problem is that for testing purposes i simply copied the [youtube sample script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) and guess what - it doesn't work either.
I've put a demonstration on my webserver [here](http://absolut-fair.com/my-yt/demo.html).

The problems probably have to do something with security settings from Youtube, as i also get the Error

> Permission denied to access property 'toString'

I was able to fix this error in Firebug by providing the **html5=1** setting, but now that there isn't a security problem with Flash (as googling the error prompt said), the Player isn't accessable via *player.playVideo()* etc, and isn't firing any events but *onYouTubeIframeAPIReady*.
I already checked the pathes and the API gets successfully included, onYouTubeIframeAPIReady gets fired and YT.Player creates a working iframe with the selected video inside. PlayerVars work fine.
It's just that after creating the player, i'm not able to access it.

I even tried setting the player-variable to global by using `window["player"]` or create an Interval that always tries to access the video. Of course, as i can't detect due to the missing onPlayerReady-Event, at first there are some errors, but after that there are no js-errors anymore, but it also does nothing.

---

**Edit1:** I just tested the example on another webserver of mine with another domain. Works fine there. My suspicion, that the problem is bound to security limitations, is getting more and more precise.
Does anybody probably know limitations in the API, where after X requests the webserver gets blocked or sth? Didn't find anything like that yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain has been banned by the google team, leading, like expected, to limitations and restrictions in API requests. The reason is most likely to be license fraugment, even though the project was still in development.